# How to write BNF statements

Tags: bnf

I understand that BNF removes ambiguity when defining the syntax of a computer language. 
I also understand that using recursion is necessary because BNF does not support iteration and recursion allows 'strings' of digits or characters to be developed.
Finally, I understand some of the symbols used in BNF like <> to enclose syntactic statements; a pipe means 'OR' and curly braces for zero or more repetitions.
However, I am still struggling to write BNF and wondered if anyone can give a few pointers.

For example, I found this exam question:
[image: OCR A Level Question June 2012]

The questions was to write BNF statements for the code, comments and statements.

I therefore wrote this definition and I was wondering if anyone could explain if my understanding of BNF is correct. If not, what pointers can you give for me and others trying to get to grips with this:

[image]

Comment: if my understanding is correct, bnf is not standardized. though you might see large similarity in different books, there could be subtle differences. in your case, comment should be a list of chars enclosed by braces, but your definition doesn't do it. also i am not sure up to what level you should right your syntax, you probably want to make it LL grammar, for example.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr Ah! Thank you. I didn't know it was no standardized. What is LL grammar?

Comment: you can try to read dragon book about compilers. i think your answer's good considering the way question is asked.

Comment: Many thanks for your thoughts. I will look into the literature you suggest. So many of the documents online are rather heavy for my purposes.

Comment: Compiler is difficult. If you want something more specific, you probably want to ask want you want to learn. Dragon book is large. It describes compiler from front to back. If you want something done in 30 minutes, it's not what you need.